# Why lower resolution with nouveau driver on external screen?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, nouveau

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Extreme Gen1 with:

- Intel i7-8750H CPU
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Max-Q 4GB
- Ubuntu 22.04.2

I have an external monitor : iiyama prolite xcb3494wqsn-b1 plugged with USB-C cable to PC

When I used :

- nvidia driver (nvidia-driver-530) I have max resolution of external screen 3440x1440

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3440 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   3840x2160     60.00 +  60.00  
   3200x1800     60.00  
   2880x1620     60.00  
   2560x1600     60.00  
   2560x1440     60.00  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.00  
   1792x1344     60.00  
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1400x900      60.00  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.00  
   896x672       60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   840x525       60.00  
   864x486       60.00  
   700x525       60.00  
   800x450       60.00  
   640x512       60.00  
   700x450       60.00  
   640x480       60.00  
   720x405       60.00  
   684x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00  
   480x270       60.00  
   400x300       60.00  
   432x243       60.00  
   320x240       60.00  
   360x202       60.00  
   320x180       60.00  
DP-1-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 connected primary 3440x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 797mm x 334mm
   3440x1440     59.97*+
   2560x1440    120.00  
   2560x1080    100.00    59.94  
   1920x1080    119.93   119.88   100.00    99.90    60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
HDMI-1-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

- nouveau drvier I have max resolution at 2560x1080 for external screen

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   3840x2160     60.00 +  60.00  
   3200x1800     60.00  
   2880x1620     60.00  
   2560x1600     60.00  
   2560x1440     60.00  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.00  
   1792x1344     60.00  
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1400x900      60.00  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.00  
   896x672       60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   840x525       60.00  
   864x486       60.00  
   700x525       60.00  
   800x450       60.00  
   640x512       60.00  
   700x450       60.00  
   640x480       60.00  
   720x405       60.00  
   684x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00  
   480x270       60.00  
   400x300       60.00  
   432x243       60.00  
   320x240       60.00  
   360x202       60.00  
   320x180       60.00  
eDP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 connected primary 2560x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 797mm x 334mm
   2560x1080     60.00*   59.94  
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94    59.93    30.00    29.97  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1400x1050     74.76    59.98  
   1600x900      59.82  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      59.97  
   1368x768      59.85  
   1280x800      59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94    59.74  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   960x720       75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.82  
   960x600       60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.82  
   800x600       70.00    65.00    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       59.88  
   864x486       59.57  
   720x576       50.00  
   700x525       74.76    59.98  
   800x450       59.82  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x512       75.02    60.02  
   700x450       59.88  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    75.00    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x405       58.99  
   720x400       70.08  
   684x384       59.85  
   640x400       59.98  
   576x432       75.00  
   640x360       59.32  
   512x384       75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x288       59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.82  
   400x300       72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.57  
   320x240       72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.13  
   320x180       59.32  
  640x480 (0x69) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
```